# SuiteScript 2.0 Estimate Not Updating

Tags: suitescript2.0

I am trying to null out a custom numeric field on an estimate. The code I am using is;

```
record.submitFields({
    type: record.Type.ESTIMATE,
    id : idNext,
    values : {
        fieldID: null
    }
});
```

It wasn't updating so I changed the value to 0 instead of null and it's still not updating the field. The field id matches to a field id on the estimate, the estimate id matches an internal is of an estimate??

Please help.

Answer (score 0):

try this

record.submitFields({
    type: record.Type.ESTIMATE,
    id : idNext,
    values : {
        fieldID: ''
    }
});